# URL encode error?

Tags: php, api, curl

My PHP code (free.php) on http://techmentry.com/free.php is

```
<?php
{
//Variables to POST
$access_token = "b34480a685e7d638d9ee3e53cXXXXX";
$message = "hi";
$send_to = "existing_contacts";

//Initialize CURL data to send via POST to the API
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://freesmsgateway.com/api_send");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
          array('access_token' => $access_token,
                'message' => urlencode('hi'),
                'send_to' => $send_to,)
          );

//Execute CURL command and return into variable $result
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//Do stuff
echo "$result";
}
?>
```

I am getting this error: THE MESSAGE WAS BLANK

This error means: "The message field was blank or was not properly URL encoded" (as told by my SMS gateway). But as you can see that my message field isn't blank.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't send an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, you would need to replace the line with the following

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "access_token=".$accesstoken."&message=".urlencode('hi')."&send_to=".$send_to);
```

I hope this solves it

Answer (score 0):

Use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)():

```
<?php
{
  $postdata = array();

  //Variables to POST
  $postdata['access_token'] = "b34480a685e7d638d9ee3e53cXXXXX";
  $postdata['message']      = "hi";
  $postdata['send_to']      = "existing_contacts";

  //Initialize CURL data to send via POST to the API
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://freesmsgateway.com/api_send");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postdata) );

  //Execute CURL command and return into variable $result
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  //Do stuff
  echo "$result";
}
?>
```